# Import class from module without ES6

Tags: javascript, material-design

I am attempting to use Material's snackbar with ES5 JavaScript. By doing this, I can't use ES6's `import` functionality. Therefore, I am referencing the CSS file and JS file through `link href='...'` and `script src='...'`.

When declaring a variable with `var snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(document.querySelector('.mdc-snackbar'))`, I receive the error:

> Snackbar.aspx:722 Uncaught ReferenceError: MDCSnackbar is not defined

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_catalogs/masterpage/Custom/snackbar/node_modules/@material/snackbar/dist/mdc.snackbar.min.css">
  <script src="../_catalogs/masterpage/Custom/snackbar/node_modules/@material/snackbar/dist/mdc.snackbar.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mdc-snackbar">
    <div class="mdc-snackbar__surface">
      <div class="mdc-snackbar__label" role="status" aria-live="polite">
        Can't send photo. Retry in 5 seconds.
      </div>
      <div class="mdc-snackbar__actions">
        <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-snackbar__action">Retry</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script>
  var snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(document.querySelector('.mdc-snackbar'));
</script>

</html>
```

How can I 'import' MDCSnackbar without using ES6's `import` functionality?

Comment: I think you should use CDN for Material-UI instead of static files. see [this](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CDN version maybe as explained in their docs [Material-ui cdn](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#cdn)here is the [github example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn) of the material-ui cdn example.